# Even after clicking cancel the form gets submitted

Tags: javascript, html, forms, form-submit, confirm

I am doing a form submission, and I am displaying a confirmation box asking the user that **if they really want to continue**. But even if the user clicks on cancel, the form is still getting submitted.

```
 <form onsubmit="return confirm('If you enter the incorrect number, the search will still be conducted and charge you for the cost of the search. do you want to continue?.')" action="http:example.com/" id="customersearch" name="customersearch" role="form" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" novalidate="novalidate">
```

How can I avoid this? Can anyone kindly tell me how to stop the form from getting submitted when the user clicks cancel?

Comment: Post a working code snippet using codepen/jsfiddle/plunker etc of your code. That would be easy to debug. Above information is not sufficient

Comment: Put your confirmation in the conditional statement and return or prevent accordingly based on the user selection

Comment: How you are submitting from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Akshay Vasu, try with below solution, you need to call onsubmit event of form

```js
function validateForm() {
   if(confirm('If you enter the incorrect number, the search will still be conducted and charge you for the cost of the search. do you want to continue?.'))
   {
      $("myform").submit();
      
   }
   else{
     alert("Invalid");
     return false;
   }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform" name="myForm" action="/action_page.php"
onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="fname">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Yes this is working example.(which uses jquery). But what is wrong with approach used in question?

Comment: @Tanmay, for that we need to check his html page which he hasn't paste. But this is global solution for submit form with confirm so i answer accordingly.

Comment: Your code worked perfectly. Thank you. In my case, I was using bootstrap and the bootstrap validation was somehow affecting my submission. Now its resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Here is working code snippet your code is also working fine:

```html
 <form onsubmit="return confirm('If you enter the incorrect number, the search will still be conducted and charge you for the cost of the search. do you want to continue?.')" action="http:example.com/" id="customersearch" name="customersearch" role="form" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" novalidate="novalidate">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

just put

```
<button type="button">Cancel</button>
```

for cancel and it will work.